# Text from button not staying in edittext when clicked?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I click on my button, it is supposed to "put the current String Text of the button" into the EditText.

But clicking on a new button replaces the existing string value in the EditText while I want it to not remove the previous input.

Ex. "When I click on a *Button* with the *Text String of "1"* in it, it appears on the editText. When I click on another *Button* with a different String, it replaces the current value in the EditText while I want them to stay.

[What my current layout looks like (Sorry for the choice colors)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8QtS.png)

```
private void LoadBtnNumbers(){
        Button[] btn = new Button[] {

                (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1),
                (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2),
                (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3),
                (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4),
                (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5),
                (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6),
                (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7),
                (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn8),
                (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn9),
        };

        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
        array.add("1");
        array.add("2");
        array.add("3");
        array.add("4");
        array.add("5");
        array.add("6");
        array.add("7");
        array.add("8");
        array.add("9");


        for(int i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {

            Random rand = new Random();
            String newString = array.get(rand.nextInt(array.size()));
            btn[i].setText(newString);

            array.remove(newString);
            String text = btn[i].getText().toString();

            btn[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("BTN","NUMBER = "+ text);
                    txtPass.setText(text);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

My code above is to get an Array of Buttons and ArrayList of Strings, to then set the text of the button randomly on start from the string Array.

Do let me know if what I imagine is even possible and how can I accomplished that.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **append** the button text to the current EditText string instead of **replacing** it, you should get the current string first, append the new value, then put the new appended string back in the EditText, like this:

```java
btn[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String newText = txtPass.getText().toString() + text;
        txtPass.setText(newText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ahh, something so simple which I didn't even think of in the first place. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
btn[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String btnTextValue = ((Button) v).getText().toStrinh();
                txtPass.setText(btnTextValue);
            }
        });
```

Comment: My bad, If you want append above ans is good.